# Why does passing `-ex` command to set breakpoint to gdb command line via bash variable fail?

Tags: bash, gdb, quotes

Why does this set a breakpoint properly:

```
gdb -ex 'break file.cpp:100' -ex run --args myProg
```

But this does not work:

```
BP1="-ex 'break file.cpp:100'"
gdb $BP1 -ex run --args myProg
```

Comment: Putting quotes in a variable doesn't work; once they're in a variable, they're treated as data, not shell syntax. See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia). Use an array to store the argument list instead of a regular variable, and ignore all suggestions involving `eval` (it's a massive bug magnet).